# Android studio - play store - fails to upload - icon is not valid

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, playback

> The icon inside your apk or android app bundle is not valid

This is the message that I am being shown, I am not sure of the reason, I had vector xml, in drawable for the icon of mic, which icon I converted to PNG and got that xml in layout tab, no functions were affected and app works fine though still issue of icon not valid is not solved 
It's my first app that I am uploading on play store, if anyone knows answer then please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Icon must feel the google requirements. Google has rules for App Icons. Look below-

- Final size: 512px x 512px
- Format: 32-bit PNG
- Color space: sRGB
- Max file size: 1024KB
- Shape: Full square – Google Play dynamically handles masking. Radius will be equivalent to 20% of icon size.
- Shadow: None – Google Play dynamically handles shadows.

Check the official docs for more info: [Google Play icon design specifications](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications)

**Edit:** You have to add PNG file to all mipmap folder with name ic_launcher.png. That will create the launcher icon for your app.

Comment: Thanks, wish someone would have told me earlier, I spent all day finding answer, thanks

Comment: Can I ask for one more help in chat

Answer (score 0):

The file must be in mipmap, not the drawable folder, and must meet the google requirements